# GeoPandas loses .crs info across notebooks

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I've run into an odd problem: when using GeoPandas (in Jupyter Notebooks) the .crs data works fine in my first notebook, then gets lost in my second one.

Just looking at the one world map that comes with the library, running this cell...

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.crs
```

... in my first notebook returns...

```
{'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

..., while in my second notebook I get...

```
{}
```

On top of (or because of) that, matching crs works in the first notebook but not the second. In notebook 1...

```
mal0 = gpd.read_file('./bird-species/E00039600_mallard.gdb', layer=0)
mal0 = mal0.to_crs(world.crs)
mal0.crs
```

returns...

```
{'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

... as expected, but in notebook 2 it throws an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fd67623093a6> in <module>
      1 mal0 = gpd.read_file('./bird-species/E00039600_mallard.gdb', layer=0)
----> 2 mal0 = mal0.to_crs(world.crs)
      3 mal0.crs

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg, inplace)
    441         else:
    442             df = self.copy()
--> 443         geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
    444         df.geometry = geom
    445         df.crs = geom.crs

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg)
    303                 raise TypeError('Must set either crs or epsg for output.')
    304         proj_in = pyproj.Proj(self.crs, preserve_units=True)
--> 305         proj_out = pyproj.Proj(crs, preserve_units=True)
    306         project = partial(pyproj.transform, proj_in, proj_out)
    307         result = self.apply(lambda geom: transform(project, geom))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py in __new__(self, projparams, preserve_units, **kwargs)
    360         # on case-insensitive filesystems).
    361         projstring = projstring.replace('EPSG','epsg')
--> 362         return _proj.Proj.__new__(self, projstring)
    363 
    364     def __call__(self, *args, **kw):

_proj.pyx in _proj.Proj.__cinit__()

RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

Does anyone know what's going with this?

Comment: As a side note, I've looked up if that RuntimeError has a reasonable solution, but all I found was this thread - https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/134 -, wherein it looks like everyone that managed to get past it did something completely different.

I tried going through a couple of the fixes suggested there, to no avail so far :(

Comment: what is `gpd.read_file('./bird-species/E00039600_mallard.gdb', layer=0).crs`?

You can't convert to a new CRS if the layer doesn't already have one

Comment: one of the data files I'm working with, from https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/55897deae4b0b6d21dd61c9d

similarly, I get (differently formatted) crs info from that data in the first notebook, but not the second notebook. It's the craziest thing.

Comment: I am trying to replicate your issue but without any success. How do you open the second notebook? Are you using the same kernel? It works for me as expected.

Comment: Yeah, weirdly enough it turns out this is sometimes solved by restarting Jupyter. Problem solved, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I can reproduce this without jupyter with geopandas 0.6.1.

This is a case of unhelpful error messages. The actual error is that your crs is not supported by geopandas.